# Why is *- syntax/operator valid in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, syntax

I made a typo in a C program and I am confused why it compiled and what the point of the syntax is. I was trying to use the multiplication assignment operator `*=` but accidentally typed `*-`. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double foo = 1.2;
    foo *- 3.4; /* I meant to type foo *= 3.4; */
    printf("%f\n", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code with `gcc -Wall ctest.c` (or g++) I get the following output:

```
ctest.c: In function `int main()':
ctest.c:5 warning: statement has no effect
```

The output of the `printf` statement when running this program is `1.200000`. Thus, the statement indeed appears to have no effect on the value of `foo`.

What is the `*-` operator? Is there a good reason why that syntax compiles even though the statement has no effect?

Comment: Two operators, `*` and unary `-`.

Comment: Wow, that was answered incredibly fast. Thanks!

Comment: There's plenty of ["rebracketing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebracketing) questions on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight but there's no way to know it's a rebracketing question until you get an answer!

Comment: @MarkRansom Well, the compiler gave OP a big hint with the "has no effect" message :)

Comment: I love these kinds of questions. I'm working on the Generalist badge, and as I haven't used c in years, questions like this really help me out :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two operators

```
foo * (-3.4);
```

With the result thrown away. There is no left-hand side to the statement, so the compiler will probably remove this statement entirely.